# How do I fix a Julia OpenCV Cxx memory leak in image capturing?

Tags: opencv, memory-leaks, julia

I have a local build of OpenCV on an intel Ubuntu system per [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/terasakisatoshi/77e64396a5546338f606426d8d95770).  Nearly identical python, c++, and julia demo programs to capture 1000 images execute mostly as expect.  The python and c++ versions work perfectly, but "top" shows that the julia version exhibits a growing use of system memory in tens of MB per second as it runs.  If left long enough the system runs out of memory and locks up.

Why does the julia code seem to result in a memory leak and how can I fix that?

```
using OpenCV
using Printf
cv = OpenCV


function main( )
    vidDevice="/dev/video0"
    cap = cv.VideoCapture(vidDevice)
    count = 1000
    while (cv.isOpened(cap) && count > 0)
        @printf("Capturing %4d\r", count)
        ret,img = cv.read(cap)
        count = count - 1
        
    end
    cv.release(cap)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()

end

main()
```

Comment: Could you raise an issue at https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/ for this and your other stackoverflow question regarding opencv-julia? I will start tackling this issue soon and having it on GitHub will make it easier to track.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a registered OpenCV.jl package. What package are you using? (the gist link you posted appears to be broken)

Comment: @SimonByrne You can use this gist to use the OpenCV package - https://gist.github.com/terasakisatoshi/77e64396a5546338f606426d8d957706

I wrote the Julia wrappers for Google Summer of Code with OpenCV organization but wasn't able to get a BinaryBuilder package done in time so this is a stopgap measure till then.

Comment: I have created an issue to track this at https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/2766

Comment: Archit, can you summarize your comments into an official answer?

Answer (score 1):

The code results in a memory leak because Julia GC does not "know" the real size of Mat Objects and thinks it is only the size of a pointer. You can get this code to work similar to Python by forcing the GC to run by inserting `GC.gc()` inside the loop but that doesn't fix the core issue which is that GC does not run automatically even when system is running out of memory.

This modified version of your code should work without any issues -

```
using OpenCV
using Printf
cv = OpenCV


function main( )
    vidDevice="/dev/video0"
    cap = cv.VideoCapture(vidDevice)
    count = 1000
    while (cv.isOpened(cap) && count > 0)
        @printf("Capturing %4d\r", count)
        GC.gc()
        ret,img = cv.read(cap)
        count = count - 1
        
    end
    cv.release(cap)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()

end

main()
```

I have created a tracker for this issue at https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/2766